# Recommended attributes and capitalization for networks in Nexus

Tags: igraph, complex-networks

I am glad, that igraph 0.6 have a possibility to get network data easily from the Nexus repository. I have been stored several networks, and I want to made them as nexus-conform as possible.

I have two questions about the attributes of networks stored in the [Nexus repository](http://nexus.igraph.org/).

Are there recommended attributes for the graph? I have found several attributes: name, Author, Citation, Description (in networks of Newman), URL

Is there any policy for using capitalized attributes for special (eg. recommended) attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the current policy is that the graph should have attributes `name`, `Author`, `Citation` and `URL`, if possible. It may have others as well. As currently all data sets are added by the nexus authors, they make sure that this policy is met. In the future, this will be hopefully different and people can just upload their data sets, and they will be published (after a quick check) automatically.

The rule of thumb with capitalization is that all attributes should be capitalized, except if you want igraph to recognize and treat your attribute specially. Currently the attributes that are treated specially are: `name` (graph, vertex and edge), `type` (vertex), `weight` (edge) and all the graphical attributes like `shape`, `width`, `label`, `size`, `color`, etc.